# Meta-analysis: estimating partial correlation coefficients using estimates from multi-level analyses

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, effect-size, degrees-of-freedom, partial-correlation

I would be very grateful if someone could offer some ideas or point to relevant literature on the calculation of partial correlation coefficients (PCCs) using estimates from multi-level analyses.

Currently we are conducting a meta-analysis which draws on data from multiple regression models and uses PCC as a common effect size metric. So, for every relevant coefficient estimate included in our meta-analysis we are estimating a PCC. Some of the models included in our meta-analysis come from multi-level analyses. Our predictors of interest are at level 1, so is the outcome measure.

The regular formula for estimating PCC is the following (Stanley and Doucouliagos 2012):

r=t/sqrt(t²+df), where t is the t-statistic of a regression coefficient and df is degrees of freedom.

To estimate PCCs, we are using *escalc* function from *metafor* package in R. Using this function, one has to provide the number of predictors, total sample size and the t-statistic as inputs.

We are a bit unsure about the correct way to estimate PCCs using estimates from multi-level models, given that the calculation of degrees of freedom in multi-level models is different from that applied in single-level regression. In particular, I am wondering what figure we should provide for mi argument (total number of predictors) when estimating PCCs from multi-level models. Should we take the sum of level 1 and level 2 predictors? Should we take into account the number of level 2 units when specifying this argument? Perhaps *escalc* is not suitable for calculating PCCs when coefficient estimates come from multi-level models at all?

Any help would be greatly appreciated – thank you very much for your time.

Comment: This is a bit of a desperation comment as I see this question has not attracted much attention yet :) thank you in advance for any suggestions!